# vimrc different colorscheme when file is read-only

Tags: vim

I have this in my .vimrc file to show a different colorscheme in gvim.

```
" Colorscheme, options for GUI only.
if has("gui_running")
    colorscheme clean
    set guioptions-=T
    set guitablabel=%t
    set background=dark
endif
```

What syntax can I use to only show a particular colorscheme depending on whether a file is readonly?

(Thanks to https://github.com/matason/vimstuff/blob/master/.vimrc for a great .vimrc example).

Comment: You cannot change the colorscheme for one buffer only, only globally. so whether a file is read only or not, doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this:

```
function CheckRo()
    if &readonly
        colorscheme moria
    else
        colorscheme sienna
    endif
endfunction
au BufReadPost * call CheckRo()
```

But beware that a coloscheme applies to all tabs and all windows in Vim.